# The Big Three implementation in linked list using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I am having a lot of trouble trying to get my copy constructor and assignment operator working for a homework problem. I am suppose to implement them recursively.

I am getting a warning saying

```
variable 'LList::head' is uninitialized on `LList::LList(const LList& a)`
```

Can someone help me with this?
Here is my code

```
class  LList {
   public:
      LList();
      void cons(int x);
      void append(int x);
      LList(const LList&);
      LList& operator = (const LList&);
      ~LList();
   private:
      struct Node {
         int item;
         Node* next;
      };
      Node* head;
}

LList::LList() {
   this->head = nullptr;  
}

void LList::cons(int x){
   Node* temp = new Node;
   temp->item = x;
   temp->next = head;
   head = temp;
}

void LList::append(int x, Node* head){
    if(isEmpty()) return cons(x);
    if(head->next == nullptr){
        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->item = x;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        head->next = temp;
    }
    append(x, head->next);
}
void LList::append(int x) {
    append(x, head);
}

LList::~LList(){
   Node* curr;
   while (head != nullptr){
      curr = head->next;
      delete head;
      head = curr;
   }
}
```

And here is what i have tried for the copy constructor and copy assignment.

```
void LList::copylist(Node* head1, Node* head2) {
    if (head1 == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    head2->item = head1->item;
    copylist(head1->next, head2->next);
}
LList::LList(const LList& a) {
    LList newlist;
    copylist(a.head, newlist.head);
}

LList& LList::operator = (const LList& a) {
    LList newlist;
    copylist(a.head, newlist.head);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: How can you run `LList newlist;` when `LList::LList()` is implicitly deleted?

Comment: "_I am suppose to implement them recursively_" - That's ... odd. What if your list contains thousands of entries? Not many stacks would survive that.

Comment: yea, its a homework on recursion

Comment: It should be fine if the function uses tail recursion, since it will usually get optimized out and replace the current operation on the stack instead of pushing a new one.

Comment: @ThomasBécavin That's a big _if_ though. If compiled for size rather than speed it will probably get ugly. I.m.o., recursion should not be near this.

Comment: Agreed.  Recursion and linked lists are a bad mix.  The copy constructor and copy assignment operator are best served using iteration not recursion.  Since this is recursion homework, using a linked list was a bad example for it.

Comment: @KericMa What is it that makes you say "_it does not feel right_"? Does it produce the wrong result somehow?

Comment: its giving me a warning saying variable 'LList::head' is uninitialized

Comment: On which line it the code? Btw, your `append(int x, Node* head)` method looks broken. Shouldn't it be `... else if(head->next == nullptr){...} else append(x, head->next);` ?

Comment: on this line `LList::LList(const LList& a) {` under LList::LList

Comment: Translating: [Your Rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what happens in `copylist`, if there is no `head2` when the code tries to `head2->item = head1->item;`